# ssh-keygen in git bash suddenly using wrong path

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash

I generated key set of keys using the method shown [here](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key).

It worked fine and I was able to register my public key and clone the git repository i needed. Then out of nowhere it stopped working. I decided to try to start over, so I backed up and deleted the old .ssh-folder but when I run ssh-keygen it suggests the following location:

```
/c/Users/MyName/.ssh/.ssh/id_rsa
```

As you can see it nests the .ssh-folder twice. When I looked in my backup, it turned out that it was the same here. The reason it stopped working must be because git or git bash or whatever is now looking in the wrong folder for my ssh-keys. I tried reinstalling git and git bash but this didn't do anything.

Does anyone know why it is nesting the .ssh-folder twice and how I might be able to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value of the environment variable `HOME`

```
echo $HOME
```

If it is `/c/Users/MyName/.ssh`,that would explain the suggestion you have.

Make sure your `HOME` is set to your `%USERPROFILE%`

Comment: This was it! I have no idea how this variable changed. For anyone who doesn't know, you can find environment variables under System > Advanced system settings > Environment variables.

Comment: @Technoshaft HOME should be `/c/Users/Myname`, not `/c/Users/Myname/.ssh`, or ssh will look for keys in `/c/Users/Myname/.ssh/.ssh`